# QGIS Atlas - Making legend and size assistant automatically update based on which area selected

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm hoping to use the atlas feature to generate a batch of maps for London postcode districts which will show supply of private indicated by size of dots within the PCD. I was wondering if it was possible to make it so the size of the dots would automatically adjust on each map generated by the atlas based on the supply within each district.

For example, in an area such as Mayfair, where number of units per development is very low, the sizes would need to be scaled down (0-10,10-20, etc..) differently to Battersea, where there are a lot of developments with larger number of units (0-100,100-200,etc..)

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS:SE! Make sure to take [the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)! This site doesn't work like a classic forum and one of the important points you'll see in the tour is that a good question usually shows a minimum amount of research on the problem at hand. I'd invite you to take a swing at various tutorials that can be found around the web like [this one](http://learngis.uk/proportional-symbol-map-qgis-2-18/) which should cover graduated/proportional symbol maps.

Comment: Once you've learned the basics of creating graduated symbology, I recommend looking into data-defined settings. Many aspects of symbology can be controlled by an expression, which can include atlas-related variables. You might also need to group your data by atlas page.